# ERROR: please confirm the keyfile is match and keyring plugin is loaded

Tags: mysql, encryption, backup, xtrabackup

I want to create a copy of my Production DB to a new instance.

There is a innobackupex running on the prod every night looks like this:

```
innobackupex --user=username --password=password --keyring-file-data=/var/lib/mysql-keyring/keyring --target-dir=mybackup-path
```

I copied the mybackup-path contents to my new instance and then prepared it by as following:

```
xtrabackup --prepare --keyring-file-data=/var/lib/mysql-keyring/keyring --target-dir=mybackup-path-in-new-server
```

then copy over files -`-copy-back` and `chowned` the data folder to mysql & everything is working

BUT I get "please confirm the keyfile is match and keyring plugin is loaded".

I have added updated my.cnf to early-plugin-load but still nothing

```
early-plugin-load = keyring_file.so
keyring_file_data = /var/lib/mysql-keyring/keyring
```

When I start mysql, and run SHOW PLUGINS, Keyring is ACTIVE,

My both instances are the same and both have ubuntu and Percona Server 5.7

I'm sure I'm missing something, and I believe it is related to keyring,
can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my issue:

Make sure that the backup taken by `xtrabackup` and the keyring file in `/var/lib/mysql-keyring/keyring` are from the same server.

Also after copying the keyring file to the destination server, make sure to `chown mysql:mysql` to it.

The Keyring file should be copied as is not the contents of the file.

To verify if things are working, you can create a new DB and some new tables, also insert some data, that are encrypted then run the following

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, CREATE_OPTIONS
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE CREATE_OPTIONS LIKE '%ENCRYPTION="Y"%';
```

You need to get the result tables. Now try to select from those tables, you should see the data inserted.